# Error 406 on Spring 3+Google App Engine on Android Studio

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, android-studio, gradle

I am using Google App Engine to develop a backend module provided by Android Studio. I am also using Spring 3 to map URL to class.Although,I have successfully used the combo on Eclipse.But on Android Studio getting a peculiar error(May be because of gradle error).Consider the following files-

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
        jcenter()
     }
    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
    }
}

repositories {
  jcenter();
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
  appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
  compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.0.RELEASE'
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
}

appengine {
   downloadSdk = true
   appcfg {
      oauth2 = true
   }
}
```

MyServlet.java . When I am accessing  conventional MyServlet the Gson get successfully loaded and returns  the required JSON.

```
 public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("application/json");

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Shop sh = new Shop();
    sh.setName("Gufran Kurshid");
    sh.setAddress("Pitampura new Delhi");
    sh.setId(5235);

    resp.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(sh));
    }
}
```

MyController.java - A normal controller URL /hello is also easily accessible.But /getDummyJSON which is made to return JSON is giving Error 406.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/greet")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloDost() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("rat");
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "Hello Dost");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getDummyJSON", produces =   MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Map getDummyJSON() {
    Map map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    map.put("status", true);
    map.put("message", "Hello Friends");
    return map;
    }
}
```

My study says the Spring is not able map and load Gson classes.Is there any thing wrong with Android Studio or my Gradle file ?

Comment: I am facing same problem!!

Comment: Shouldn't you call `/greet/getDummyJSON` instead of `/getDummyJSON` . Also, try to keep your requestMappings lower-case. Secondly, it's a 406, means it depends on how you are calling it...no problem with controller method.

Comment: do you have any MessageConverters configured?